Change background on hover
I want the whole of the background to change on hover. At the moment the width of change in color hugs the width of the original text plus padding and not the whole width of the submemu.
I tried the following.
HTML CODE
`
home

home2

link1
link link2



CSS CODE
.dropdown {
height: 50px;
width: auto;
padding: 10px 20px;
color: white;
background: grey;
}

.submenu {
display: none;
}

.submemu li a:hover,
.submemu li a:focus{
background: blue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
width : 100%;
padding : 10px 20px;
white-space : nowrap;
}`

The results of the above code only changed the background of the dropdown-content around the text with the padding but not the whole width of the container submemu.

Instead Of:

.submenu li a:hover,
.submemu li a:focus,{
background: blue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 20px;
white-space: nowrap;
}


.submenu li:hover,
.submemu li:focus,{
background: blue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
display: list-item;
padding: 10px 20px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

